# How render component in v-for by button from parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vuetify.js

How i can render v-if component by button(button in parent) click inside v-for loop? and should render only in that item where clicked

```
<div v-for="item in items">
  <button @click >Show child<button>
  <div>{{item.name}}</div>
  <child v-if="this button clicked" :item="item"><child>
<div>
```

Comment: Show also your `items` content

Comment: no matter rly. its like input with method to commit to store item.newtext with info from input(its works fine)

Comment: @RemiFokz I solved similar issue before, check out [this post](/a/54252743/3634538) and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can take advantage of an item... index available in v-for directive (e.g. `v-for="(item, i) in items"`), to bind it (index of the item) to the function which shows an item by changing it's property:</strike>

**Update**: Initial answer has been deleted after requirements refinement.

Since you prefer to keep from mutation of items, you can wrap them in `Map` object (as keys) and keep visibility settings separately as `Map` values. Unfortunately, as far as I know, for the time being Vue.js does not support reactivity for `Map` objects, that's why I have to trigger rerendering manually by using `forceUpdate`:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<p>Visible child</p>'
})

new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  template: `
<div>
  <div v-for="item in items">
    <button @click="toggleChild(item)">Toggle child</button>
    <div>{{item.name}}</div>
    <child v-if="isVisible(item)" :item="item"></child>
  </div>
</div>
`,
  data () {
    return {
      itemsMap: new Map(
        [
          { name: 'test1' },
          { name: 'test2' }
        ].map(item => [item, { visible: false }])
      )
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleChild(item) {
      this.itemsMap.set(item, { visible: !this.itemsMap.get(item).visible });
      this.$forceUpdate();
    },
    isVisible(item) {
      return this.itemsMap.get(item).visible;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    items: function() {
      return Array.from(this.itemsMap.keys());
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: im getting items(array of large objects) from store, and not sure to need add more properties to them

Comment: @RemiFokz Hi, I have updated the answer with a variant that does not mutate original items, hopefully it may be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store info about state of every item (if it was clicked) in your data. Then, when you click on button you should update clicked property for particular item. Finally if item.clicked is set on true you will show your child component (or any other html).

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
      <button @click="item.clicked = true" >Show child</button>
      {{item.name}}
      <div v-if="item.clicked">Item child</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data: function() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'test1',
          clicked: false
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'test2',
          clicked: false
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'test3',
          clicked: false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: im getting items(array of large objects) from store, and not sure to need add more properties to them

Answer (score 0):

Plain and simple you just have to set some flag for latter `v-if`:

```html
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in items">
    <button @click="$set(item, 'shown', true)">Show child</button>
    <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
    <div v-if="item.shown">Child component</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here, `$set()` is used because initial `item` could lack `shown` field, so setting it directly with `item.shown=true` won't be reactive.

You can also hide button after click:

```
<button @click="$set(item, 'shown', true)" v-if="!item.shown">Show child</button>
```

To *toggle* visibility you just have to do it like this:

```
<button @click="$set(item, 'shown', !item.shown)">
  {{ item.shown ? 'Hide' : 'Show' }} child
</button>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6vgxn79s/)

Comment: @RemiFokz Updated my answer with toggle variant